# Is there a way to do a multiple value comparison inline?

Tags: f#, comparison

I feel silly for even asking this because it seems so trivial but my brain is failing me. If I had the following:

```
let a, b, c = 1, 1, 1
```

Is there an eligant way to determine if a, b, and c all hold the same value. Something like:

```
let result = (a = b = c)
```

This fails because the expression `a = b` returns true and the next expression results in `true = c` and complains that it was expecting int, not bool. The only thing I can think of is:

```
a = b && a = c && b = c
```

which won't work when I want to add more variables.

Really what I'm trying to do is this:

```
let same (x: string * string * string) =
    match x with
    | (a, a, a) -> true
    | _ -> false
```

I was hoping that I could match all the elements into one element and if they were different it would move on, but it says on the second element in the match that it has already been bound.

Comment: This is sweet, I just started learning F# and my brain is flailing around, it's like C# all over again.

Comment: If you had a sequence of some sort rather than a tuple then this would be trivial, but with a tuple, I don't have any good ideas... Also note that `a = b && a = c && b = c` is excessive and could be reduced to `a = b && a = c` since if `a` = `b` and `a` = `c` then `b` must obviously = `c`.

Comment: How would this be done if I was using a sequence, perhaps the solution is to tuck them into a sequence. And good call on the excesive assignment, my head was thinking about recursively comparing values in an unknown sized tuple.

Comment: I'm sure there is a more efficient approach, but `myseq |> Seq.pairwise |> Seq.forall (fun (a, b) -> a = b)` is simple and painless (or `myseq |> Seq.pairwise |> Seq.forall ((<||) (=))` if you're a fan of point-free).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To check if every value in a list is the same:

```
let rec same = function
  | x::y::_ when x <> y -> false
  | _::xs -> same xs
  | [] -> true
```

Usage

```
let a, b, c = 1, 1, 1
same [a; b; c] //true
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let same (a, b, c) = a = b && b = c
```

Answer (score 3):

I would try to use the forall function in order to determine if all of the numbers are same.

```
let list = [a; b; c;];;
List.forall (fun n -> n = a) list;;
val it : bool = true
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution produces exactly the required syntax. Surprisingly to myself, is fairly fast. Also, is seems to be a good example of using monads, also known as [Computation Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx).

```
// Generic
let inline mOp1<'a> op sample x = op sample x, sample
let inline mOp2<'a> op1 op2 (b, sample) x = op1 b (op2 sample x), sample

// Implementation for (=) and (&&)
let (==) = mOp1 (=)
let (&=) = mOp2 (&&) (=)

// Use
let ret1 = a == b &= c &= d &= e |> fst
```

#### How it works

The approach is a very simplified *State monad*. The monadic type is a tuple of `(bool, 'T)`. The first component is the boolean value of ongoing calculation, and the second is the sample value to compare with.

`(==)` would initialize the monad, similar to `Delay` operator.
`(&=)` is used for all subsequent comparisons. It is similar to `Bind` operator.
We don't need `Return` because `fst` would serve pretty fine.
`mOp1` and `mOp2` are abstractions over the logical operations. These allow defining your own operators. Here are examples of `or-equal` and `and-greater-than`:

```
let (|=) = mOp2 (||) (=)
let (.>) = mOp1 (>)
let (&>) = mOp2 (&&) (>)
// Use
let ret2 = a == b |= c |= d |= e |> fst // if any of b,c,d,e equals to a
let ret3 = 5 .> 3 &> 4 |> fst // true: 5>3 && 5>4
let ret4 = 5 .> 3 &> 8 &> 4 |> fst // false
```

#### Performance

I really enjoyed the beautiful solution by @ildjarn, but constructing `List` is quite slow, so my primary goal was performance.
Running a chain of 8 comparisons, 10 million times:

- 04972ms `a=b && a=с && ...`
- 23138ms `List`-based
- 12367ms monadic