# F# Meta-programming: is it possible to make IF X = 1 OR 2 syntax?

Tags: f#, programming-languages, metaprogramming, nemerle

I want to simplify expression `if(x == 1 || x == 2)`.
I wish I could write `if(x == 1 or 2)` but there is no syntax for that.
Other possibility is to use Contains or Any method like: `if([1,2].Contains(x))` but this involves unnecessary call.

Can I create some operator which allows me to do this ?

In Nemerle language I can write macro:

```
macro @|||(left, right)
  match (left)
    | <[ $x == $y ]> => <[ $x == $y || $x == $right ]>
    | _ => Message.Error("Error"); <[ ]>
```

And then usage:

```
if (x == 1 ||| 2) { .. }
```

Can I create operator in such way in F# ?

Comment: I never understand why people want to invent complicated new macros/constructs/functions in order to save three characters of code ("simplify").  In my opinion, it is better for code to be slightly longer and 'standard', rather than slightly shorter and use some one-off abstraction created by the author that I have to go look up the definition of.

Comment: The "Contains" approach is more general anyway, because it doesn't require you to know the count of the operands in advance. In languages that provide an operator for testing membership in a list, the following idiom is quite common (example in Python): `if x in [1,2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `|>` to accomplish this, borrowing from a common use of one of the haskell monoid instances.

```
let appendResults f g = (fun x -> f(x) || g(x))
let f x = x=1
let g x = x=2
let inline (>>||) x y = (appendResults f g) x y
let x = 1
if(x |> (1 >>|| 2)) then printfn "true" else printfn "false"
```

For arbitrary numbers of arguments, just mimic the relevant `mconcat` method from haskell for the same effect, perhaps like this:

```
let rec concatResults = function
| [] -> (fun x -> false)
| (x:xs) -> appendResults x (concatResults xs)
```

Honestly though, you may as well just use Contains. If there is any special overhead doing that I doubt it really matters.

Comment: No, you do not need to know anything about _monoids_ to write a trivial `if` condition.

Comment: You don't. This is however a frequent way you'd use the `(Monoid b) => Monoid (a -> b)` instance. For instance, you could implement a horribly impractical primality test something like `isPrime = getAny . mconcat(map (Any.(==)) primes)`, which is bottom for non-prime numbers and true for prime ones. For the implementation of the methods, see http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/libraries/base/src/Data-Monoid.html.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with Brian's comment that constructing a macro in order to save three characters is probably not a good idea. This will only make the program harder to read (for those who do not know your custom macros or changed meaning of operators).

Moreover, it is quite likely that you could write the same logic in a more concise way using standard F# constructs like pattern matching. For example:

```
match x with
| 1 | 2 -> printfn "yes"
| _     -> printfn "no"
```

The idiomatic solution will depend on the concrete case, which is hard to judge from the example you gave.

Comment: In Nemerle, the '||' operator itself is a macro from the standard library. You can redefine it to handle both usages, thereby avoiding the custom operator problem. ^_^

Comment: +1 I think this is the most definitive/idiomatic approach to the problem in F#.

Comment: @DonReba Yes, I understand that the Nemerle macro system is more powerful than operator overloading in F#. That is quite neat (i.e. you can define things like F# computation expressions or queries without waiting for a new version of the compiler). On the other hand, it is pretty scary, because people may twist the language and write code that only they will understand. Difficult trade-off to make!

Comment: So this opinion is understandable but I think macros system is fine part of meta-programming and not "harder to read". For example Nemerle language itself is full of macros and it doesn't confuse it's developers.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Brian and Tomas; it makes a little **practical** sense to invent your own macros that might be used just a few times.
However, I *do* find it very interesting from the point of studying the internals of functional languages.
Consider this:

```
// Generic
let inline mOp1<'a> op sample x = op sample x, sample
let inline mOp2<'a> op1 op2 (b, sample) x = op1 b (op2 sample x), sample

// Implementation for (=) and (||)
let (==) = mOp1 (=)
let (|=) = mOp2 (||) (=)

// Use
let ret1 = x == 1 |= 2 |> fst
```

You may find more details, other operators, and performance measurement here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11552429/974789

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly hackish, but it does work

```
let x = 1
let inline (|||) a b = [a;b]
let inline (==) a b = b |> List.exists (fun t -> t=a)

if x == (1 ||| 2) then printfn "true" else printfn "false"
```

It requires a custom operator for both or and equals.  It would not be hard to modify this to support arbitrary or chains

Of course if you only need 2 numbers you can do

```
let x = 1
let inline (|||) a b = (a,b)
let inline (==) a (c,d) = a=c ||a=d

if x == (1 ||| 2) then printfn "true" else printfn "false"
```

Comment: good but it overrides = too, interesting part will be without overriding = alike in macro example

Comment: @МарияШарапова - I think this would be tricky - the compiler infers that `=` has type signature `'a -> 'a -> bool` and most solutions would require two different types

Answer (score 0):

This works by converting a tupple to an array, so do not expect the best performance.

```
let inline (==) a b = 
    Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.GetTupleFields(b) 
        |> Array.exists((=) a)
```

Example:

```
3 == (1,2)      // false
3 == (1,2,3)    // true
```