# Is there a language construct in F# for testing if a number is between two other numbers (in a range)?

Tags: f#, operators, range

I am looking for a more succinct F# equivalent of:

```
myNumber >= 2 && myNumber <= 4
```

I imagine something like

```
myNumber >=< (2, 4)
```

Is there some kind of operation like this?

Comment: Largely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477407/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-multiple-value-comparison-inline

Comment: Alternatively, for pattern matches, you can consider a `Between a b` active pattern, which helps in readability.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no native operator, but you could define your own one.

```
let inline (>=<) a (b,c) = a >= b && a<= c
```

Comment: This sounds great, but when I try using the operator, I get "this value is not a function and cannot be applied" on the left-hand value. How should this be used?

Comment: @Saber - I got confused as to whether or not operator definitions were with tuples or in the more normal style.

Answer (score 10):

[John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915508/is-there-a-language-construct-in-f-for-testing-if-a-number-is-between-two-other/17915512#17915512) is exactly what you asked for, and the most practical solution.  But this got me wondering if one could define operator(s) to enable a syntax closer to normal mathematical notation, i.e., `a <= b <= c`.

Here's one such solution:

```
let inline (<=.) left middle = (left <= middle, middle)
let inline (.<=) (leftResult, middle) right = leftResult && (middle <= right)
let inline (.<=.) middleLeft middleRight = (middleLeft .<= middleRight, middleRight)

1 <=. 3 .<=. 5 .<= 9  // true
1 <=. 10 .<= 5   // false
```

A few comments on this:

- I used the `.` character to indicate the "middle" of the expression
- `.` was a very deliberate choice, and is not easily changeable to some other character you like better (e.g. if you perhaps like the look of `1 <=@ 3 @<= 5` better).  [The F# compiler changes the associativity and/or precedence of an operator based on the operator symbol's first character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx).  We want standard left-to-right evaluation/short-circuiting, and `.` enables this.
- A 3-number comparison is optimized away completely, but a 4+ number comparison results in [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) that allocates tuples and does various other business that isn't strictly necessary:

  [image: Generated CIL]

Comment: This isn't obvious enough for common usage, also I'm not sure what you would even use this for, `a <= b <= c` is typically used for problem statements, not for value checks.

Comment: This is exactly what OP asked for, ask them how they plan to use it. Question is how to define an operator to check if a number is between two other numbers, I show how to enable the syntax `if 0 <=. x .<= 10 then ...`, provide a link to relevant documentation on custom operators, and include a basic IL analysis, and this deserves a -1?  Brutal.

Comment: A downvote simply indicates disagreement.  It isn't meant as an attack.

Comment: Actually, a downvote is meant for a "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).  Do you think this answer meets that criteria?

Comment: And I consider this answer somewhat dangerously incorrect.  You don't have to agree, that's why people can vote both up and down, but that is still what I think.

Comment: Please indicate what part of the code is incorrect, so I can edit the answer to be more useful.

Comment: As I previously stated, this code isn't obvious.  Even having the implementation immediately available, it still takes some work to figure out what it is doing.  If I were code reviewing something that had this usage in it, I would flag it as difficult to maintain.

Comment: I like the intention of this answer, and I think it is academically very interesting. It may be a little surprising for someone reading the code, however. This may be the fault of computer languages in general? Or an issue with the nature of programming computers? thanks.

Comment: @Saber: There's nothing wrong with the computer. Mathematica allows `1<x<3` just fine.

Comment: @JordanMorris No, there are plenty languages that allow this syntax (well, without the necessity of the dots). It has even been considered for F# at one point, which speaks towards this being _common enough_ to be potentially put in the language. They opted not to. But it is an excellent answer and showcases the flexibility of the language.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some kind of operation like this?

Great question! The answer is "no", there isn't, but I wish there was.

[Latkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915508/is-there-a-language-construct-in-f-for-testing-if-a-number-is-between-two-other/17936908#17936908) is nice, but it doesn't short-circuit evaluate. So if the first test fails the remaining subexpressions still get evaluated, even though their results are irrelevant.

FWIW, in [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica) you can do `1<x<2` just like mathematics.